# Was the Iron Giant a war machine bent on human destruction?

Tags: character, the-iron-giant

First, the weaponry. Well, I vaguely recall weaponry. The IG has powerful weapons. I could understand that they may have been for defense only, but since he's a machine and would he had been a research robot they wouldn't have put any weapons on him at all.

Secondly, the dent in the IG head. Amnesia right?!?

I'm just saying that it seems that the *Iron Giant* is a story about how a war machine landed on earth and would have destroyed the planet had it not been for his amnesia.

[image]

Comment: Why would you think he has amnesia?  Just because of a dent in his head? Is there a specific scene in the film that would suggest this?

Comment: The little boy suggests it actually.

Comment: Oh, okay.  It's been a long time since I have seen it.

Comment: Yeah I have the VHS copy and I've wondered about it for a while. He landed in earth either accidentally or purposely with the intention of destroying it, but humans were lucky due to the permanent damage to his head. There's also a scene where his defense system is triggered and he displays his laser canon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this scene that seems missing from the movies after its release in 1999 that is now available in a director's cut where the Iron Giant is dreaming and he has a nightmare of him, along with hundreds of other giant robots, storming cities and then eventually destroying the planet. In the nightmare, he sees a reflection of himself in full destruction mode and wakes up frightened.

During this nightmare, there are two alternating refrains: one man saying "you don't even know what it is or where is came from!" And the other is the boy saying "you're not going to hurt me are you?"

Then we have to consider that after the Iron Giant collides with the nuclear missile, he is still not destroyed. This suggests he was built to withstand attacks and weapons, thus making him a war machine. The perfect one.